# Stripe Payment gateway throws an exception on live server working fine on local server

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am facing an issue on stripe payment gateways. I have integrated stripe payment using their library given at [Github](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/releases)
and following  [Stripe Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/charges)

On first step i setup API key using secret key, then i created customer finally i charged that particular customer.

**Full Code**

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey( $stripe_secret_key );

    try {
            $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                    "source" => $stripeToken,
                    "email" => $user_email
                )
            );
            $stripe_user_id = $customer->id;


        // charge customer by customer ID //
        $charge_amount = $stripe_payable_amount * 100;
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            'amount' => $charge_amount,
            'currency' => $CurrentCurrency,
            'customer' => $stripe_user_id

        ));

    } catch ( Exception $e ) {


        echo  $e->getMessage();

    }
```

**Above code sent an exception message as shown below:**

```
Could not connect to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_********). Please check your internet connection and try again. If this problem persists, you should check Stripe's service status at https://twitter.com/stripestatus, or let us know at support@stripe.com. (Network error [errno 7]: Failed connect to api.stripe.com:443; Operation now in progress)
```

I contacted strip on twitter they said your DNS is miss configured on sever. I checked with our network admin. There is no change made from our side. Stripe API was working fine on same day.

[image]

Same code is working on localhost.I used same **Test API keys** on local server as my staging environment.

Please give me any hint to troubleshoot it.

Comment: This is most likely an issue with configuration somewhere between your live server and Stripe's servers. It might be that there's a firewall/proxy that's not whitelisting Stripe's servers for outgoing connections, for example. If you're able to, you could try some basic networking troubleshooting such as pinging Stripe's servers from your live server, tracerouting, etc.

Comment: I will ask our network team to futher troubleshoot it.

Comment: If this is host on AWS you should check outbound traffic or NAT gateway

Comment: Adiii, yes our hosting provider is Aws, our instance can resolve the address, but it shows error for pirt 80 and 443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the above error, it has nothing to do with code as same code is working on local server. I deployed it on an another server it worked as well.

Then i checked with our AWS support they mentioned they blocked our port 443. It was being used to send lot of traffic to another website due to malicious code on our server. After they unblock this port Stripe started working again.