# Laravel cannot not connect to Stripe

Tags: laravel

I have trouble connecting to Stripe with my Laravel / React application. Locally it works and the same code on a Digital Ocean droplet doesn't. I get this message:

```
Could not connect to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/upcoming?customer=cus_XXXXXXXXXX). Please check your internet connection and try again. If this problem persists, you should check Stripe's service status at https://twitter.com/stripestatus, or let us know at support@stripe.com. (Network error [errno 7]: )
```

That is the error message from Laravel. The important part is `(Network error [errno 7]: )`. It has to do with CURL that encounters this error: `CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (error code 7)`.

Also I would expect something like this `(Network error [errno 7]: Failed connect to api.stripe.com:443; Operation now in progress)`. Not a blank space after the colon.

I have tried this:

- The server uses SSL (https://xxxxx.xxx)
- Reboot the server
- Redeploy the application
- Clear caches for config, route, view etc.
- php artisan optimize:clear
- Re-run composer
- Checked my Stripe API keys
- Tried manually to connect fromt the shell with curl and it works.
- Tried https://github.com/stripe/stripe-reachability#stripe-reachability

For reference, you can see the error on https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html and means :

```
CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (7) - Failed to connect() to host or proxy.
```

Comment: Is your website using https?

Comment: Yes, it uses HTTPS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an issue in the code, you may need to check your server hosting provider.

BTW, you may need to look at [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56399250/stripe-payment-gateway-throws-an-exception-on-live-server-working-fine-on-local). It's the same.
It is solved with him by changing the server and when communicating with the host provider, he found that the port is blocked because of high traffic.

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it addresses the general cause of the issue. In my case it was the Centos 8 server that blocked outgoing connections. Fixed it with opening up for that with `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on`. `-P` set the variable permanently. Previously it was set without `-P` so a server reboot cleared the setting.

Comment: @Cudos That `setsebool` worked for me — thank you!